# Format a float as fixed point with Jackson

Tags: java, floating-point, jackson, number-formatting

I've searched the Jackson docs, but can't find any good documentation for the `pattern` of `@JsonFormat` for floating point numbers.

Given a field

```
@JsonProperty("Cost")
private Double cost;
```

How can I get Jackson to format it as fixed point number with four digits precision in decimal format with `@JsonFormat`?

PS: I know one should not use floats for money. Spare us the discussion, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @Veselin's answers I'm using

```
public class DoubleDecimalSerializerWithSixDigitPrecisionAndDotSeparator
    extends JsonSerializer<Double> {

  @Override
  public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider serializers)
      throws IOException {
    generator.writeNumber(String.format(Locale.US, "%.6f", value));
  }
}
```

The use case is the generation of CSVs in Germany, so I don't care for JSON formatting and want a "." as a decimal separator.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify your own formatter in custom serializer class.

```
    formatter = new DecimalFormat();
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    formatter.setGroupingUsed(false);
    DecimalFormatSymbols sym = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    sym.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(sym);
```

Then, in actual serialize method:

```
    final String output = formatter.format(value);
    jsonGenerator.writeNumber(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a custom Serializer for that. Something like

```
 @JsonProperty("amountOfMoney")
 @JsonSerialize(using = MySerializer.class)
 private Double cost;

 public class MySerializerextends JsonSerializer<Double> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {  
        double roundedValue = value*10000;
        roundedValue = Math.round(roundedValue );
        roundedValue = roundedValue /10000;          
        generator.writeNumber(roundedValue );
    }
 }
```

You can see about the class here 
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html

The rounding part might not be the best. You can do it as you prefer ;) Using decimal format can work too. If you use writeNumber it will print the value as a number in the result Json. That's why I changed my answer from writeString and using decimal format.

You should be able to use pattern of @JsonFormat for that if the implementation allows it.

> Datatype-specific additional piece of configuration that may be used
>   to further refine formatting aspects. This may, for example, determine
>   low-level format String used for Date serialization; however, exact
>   use is determined by specific JsonSerializer

But with jackson I believe it works only for dates.

Comment: `pattern` is of no use here?

Comment: I believe with jackson it is used only for dates.